# POJO-like class in Python

Tags: python, object-oriented

I simply want to organize some data (class= `MarketOnCloseSecurity`) to be used in another class `MarketOnClosePortfolio`. The former class would not have any methods but just a constructor that includes a ticker for a company `symbol` and two Pandas dataframes `bars` and `signals`.

```
class MarketOnCloseSecurity():
    """Encapsulates the notion of a portfolio of positions based
    on a set of signals as provided by a Strategy.

    Requires:
    symbol - A stock symbol which forms the basis of the portfolio.
    bars - A DataFrame of bars for a symbol set.
    signals - A pandas DataFrame of signals (1, 0, -1) for each symbol.
   """

    def __init__(self, symbol, bars, signals):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.bars = bars
        self.signals = signals
```

Now the `MarketOnClosePortfolio` would have all the methods to calculate a portfolio.

Is creating a class with essentially no methods (besides constructor) in python a good practice?

The idea is to pass `MarketOnClosePortfolio` a list of `MarketOnCloseSecurity` objects.

An alternative (non-OOP) solution would do something like `list_of_MOCS = [{'symbol_1':(bars_1,signals_1)},...,{'symbol_N':(bars_N,signals_N)}]` so basically a list containing a map with the key being the ticker and value being a tuple of the two dataframes.

`MarketOnClosePortfolio` will identify the positions (buy/sell) and how based on each `MarketOnCloseSecurity` and form a Portfolio Dataframe. It will then calculate metrics, such as holdings, cash, and returns based on the summation of each `MarketOnCloseSecurity`. The code is not complete, but I have included it for reference.

```
class MarketOnClosePortfolio(Portfolio):
    """Encapsulates the notion of a portfolio of positions based
    on a set of signals as provided by a Strategy.

    Requires:
    market_on_close_securities
    initial_capital - The amount in cash at the start of the portfolio."""

    def __init__(self, market_on_close_securities, initial_capital=100000.0):
        self.market_on_close_securities = market_on_close_securities
        self.initial_capital = float(initial_capital)
        self.positions = self.generate_positions()

    def generate_positions(self):
        #loop through each MOCS (market_on_close_security) to calculate positions

        # Initialize index for positions Dataframe. Picking index 0 was arbitary they all have same index length
        positions = pd.DataFrame(index=self.market_on_close_securities[0].signals.index).fillna(0.0)
        for security in self.market_on_close_securities:
            positions[security.symbol] = 100 * security.signals['signal'] # This strategy buys 100 shares

        return positions

    def backtest_portfolio(self):

        portfolio_series = self.positions[self.symbol] * self.bars[0]['close_price'].astype(float)

        pos_diff = self.positions.diff()

        # Will need to use this for multiple columns (Eventually)
        symbol_columns = [self.symbol]

        portfolio = pd.DataFrame(index=self.bars[0].index, columns=symbol_columns)
        portfolio[self.symbol] = portfolio_series.values

        # Sum holdings from each company
        portfolio['holdings'] = portfolio.sum(axis=1)
        portfolio['cash'] = self.initial_capital - (pos_diff[self.symbol] * self.bars[0]['close_price'].astype(float)).cumsum()
        portfolio['cash'][0] = self.initial_capital
        portfolio['total'] = portfolio['cash'] + portfolio['holdings']
        portfolio['returns'] = portfolio['total'].pct_change()

        return portfolio
```

The `backtest_portfolio()` will determine the total returns/holdings based on each `MarketOnCloseSecurity`. This implementation is not complete, and is currently the method used when `MarketOnClosePortfolio` was adapted for only one security.

Comment: I think it's ok. But, most of time, i use NamedTuple for POJO like objects. Not sure that it is possible with Dataframes.

Comment: [`namedtuple`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) are awesome. You can inherit from them too in cases where you don't need to alter them just a tiny bit - like [this](https://repl.it/EE2o/1)

Comment: Knowing how you would use this data into `MarketOnClosePortfolio` will help us give more taillored advices.

Comment: Updated with what I have so far. Let me know what you think! Also thanks for the input so far from everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading

> An alternative (non-OOP) solution would do something like `list_of_MOCS = [{'symbol_1':(bars_1,signals_1)},...,{'symbol_N':(bars_N,signals_N)}]` so basically a list containing a map with the key being the ticker and value being a tuple of the two dataframes.

I thought, that a better alternative would be:

```
MOCS = {
    'symbol_1': (bars_1, signals_1),
    'symbol_2': (bars_2, signals_2),
    ...
    'symbol_N': (bars_N, signals_N),
}
```

Especially given the fact that `pd.DataFrame(MOCS)` would yield a valid structure.

However, reading at your usage in `generate_positions` and expected usage in `backtest_portfolio`; and especially the fact that you will need to explode the data-structure anyway, I would keep the class approach and use `collections.namedtuple` as largely suggested in the comments. It provides both the advantages of a class (attributes access) and a tuple (immutable + index access).

I would however change `generate_positions` to create a dictionnary that will hold the structure of the resulting dataframe before building said dataframe. And incorporate that method directly into the constructor as it does not provide much added value on its own:

```
from collections import namedtuple


MarketOnCloseSecurity = namedtuple('MarketOnCloseSecurity', 'symbol bars signals')


class MarketOnClosePortfolio(Portfolio):
    """Encapsulates the notion of a portfolio of positions based
    on a set of signals as provided by a Strategy.

    Requires:
    market_on_close_securities
    initial_capital - The amount in cash at the start of the portfolio."""

    def __init__(self, market_on_close_securities, initial_capital=100000.0):
        self.market_on_close_securities = market_on_close_securities
        self.initial_capital = float(initial_capital)

        #loop through each MOCS (market_on_close_security) to calculate positions
        securities = {
            security.symbol: 100 * security.signals['signal'] # This strategy buys 100 shares
            for security in market_on_close_securities
        }
        self.positions = pd.DataFrame(securities)

    def backtest_portfolio(self):
        ...
```

I would also extend the `namedtuple` to provide extra utilities methods:

```
class MarketOnCloseSecurity(namedtuple('MarketOnCloseSecurity', 'symbol bars signals')):
    def buy_shares(self, amount):
        return amount * self.signals['signal']

    def close_price(self):
        return self.bars['close_price'].astype(float)
```

So that you can have more meaningful actions in `MarketOnClosePortfolio`:

```
class MarketOnClosePortfolio(Portfolio):
    """Encapsulates the notion of a portfolio of positions based
    on a set of signals as provided by a Strategy.

    Requires:
    market_on_close_securities
    initial_capital - The amount in cash at the start of the portfolio."""

    def __init__(self, market_on_close_securities, initial_capital=100000.0):
        self.market_on_close_securities = market_on_close_securities
        self.initial_capital = float(initial_capital)

        securities = {
            security.symbol: security.buy_shares(100)
            for security in market_on_close_securities
        }
        self.positions = pd.DataFrame(securities)

    def backtest_portfolio(self):
        # use security.close_price() for any security in self.marke_on_close_securities if you need to
        ...
```